# Bayes estimate of beta distribution

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to derive Bayes estimate of a beta distribution.

We toss n coins i.i.d., and get X heads. Give the prior distribution for $\theta$ of the coin is beta(a,b), Bayes estimate maximize the poster distribution, which is also a beta distribution beta(a+X, b+n-X)

Basically we're maximizing:

$\int_0^1 \theta^{a+X-1}(1-\theta)^{b+n-X-1}\theta d\theta$

And the result is: $\theta=\frac{a+X}{b+n-X}$. How to derive this from the integral?

Comment: Do you know what constant $c$ makes $c\cdot \theta^{\alpha}(1-\theta)^{\beta}\mathbf 1_{\theta \in [0,1]}$ a valid density function. Can you use such information to evaluate $\int_0^1 \theta^{a+X-1}(1-\theta)^{b+n-X-1}\mathrm d\theta$?

Comment: misleading title. Beta is the prior, you are estimating the $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the posterior distribution is the beta distribution $(a+X, b+n-X)$. The [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mean) of the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) $(\alpha,\beta)$ is $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$ hence the posterior mean is $\hat\theta=(a+X)/(a+b+n)$.

Note that $0\leqslant X\leqslant n$ with full probability hence $0\lt\hat\theta\lt1$ with full probability. (By contrast the suggestion $\hat\theta=(a+X)/(b+n-X)$ in your post is absurd since if $X$ is large, $\hat\theta$ can be as large as $(a+n)/b$, which can be larger than $1$.)

Comment: One more question, why $E[\theta]$ is the estimator $T(X,n)$ to minimize the total error $\int_0^1E[(T(X,n)-p)^2]*posterior*dp$?

Comment: There is no p in your question. Please start making the effort of posting clear questions, either in posts or in comments.

Answer (score -1):

The bayes estimate is simply the mean of beta distribution $E[\theta]$, which should be $\theta=\frac{a+X}{b+n-X}$.